# SSRS graph records by date

Tags: sql, reporting-services, graph

I have a dataset that returns all the records in a database where the "entered_date" field is within the last calendar week.

I want to graph these records by day so that each point on a line graph shows the number of records for that day of the week.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this with a graph object in SSRS? Is it better to have a dataset that returns the number of jobs last monday, last tuesday, last wednesday etc or can I do this with an expression in the graph object? (that latter is my preferred option).

Olly

Comment: i try to keep SSRS as simple as possible and do everything in the SQL, however what have you tried thus far?

Comment: Please provide a sample of the dataset that drives the chart.

Comment: The data set currently is really basic as I just want the count.

The query is

SELECT
  Service.Service_RecID
  ,Service.Date_Entered
FROM
  Service
WHERE
  date_entered >=  dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, getdate()) - 1, 0)
and
date_entered < dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, getdate()), 0)


which returns data such as 

64734564, 01,01,2013 01:01:00
64867345, 02,01,2013 02:02:00
64734994, 01,01,2013 01:11:43
54867225, 02,01,2013 02:02:00
etc

So I want to graph the number of records return which fall on a Monday, Tuesday, etc with each day having a point on the graph.